# How to Split a Big Postscript file (3000 pages) into one individual file per page (using Windows 7)?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, eps, ps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GhostScript noob help - Breaking a multipage PDF file into many single page  PS or EPS files.](https://superuser.com/questions/225907/ghostscript-noob-help-breaking-a-multipage-pdf-file-into-many-single-page-ps-o)

Hi,

I'm having trouble doing the following:

I have a big PDF file that I converted to postscript (for commercial printing). The resulting file is too big to be processed by the printer (machine).

I've been trying to find a way to either:

Convert from the original (many pages) PDF file to many Postscript file (one postcript file per PDF page in original PDF file(.

Convert from PDF to PS (or even EPS). - *I managed to do this* 
Then split the PS file into a collection of smaller files.

I've tried using Ghostscript, but it is all gibberish to me.

Thanks.

PS. If you have a good GS tutorial (for dummies?), please share the link.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/225907/ghostscript-noob-help-breaking-a-multipage-pdf-file-into-many-single-page-ps-o/225930#225930

Answer (score 1):

If you have `eps` files try [`epssplit`](http://home.clara.net/nox/software/epssplit/epssplit.html).

Answer (score 0):

I know this product will allow you to take a PDF and split it, so with the knowledge you already have this may be the easiest way.

http://www.pdfsam.org/

Good luck

Comment: That is a program for PDF files. Thanks for the help.